# Calling stored procedure from C# code

Tags: asp.net, database, stored-procedures

[image: ss]

I have a stored procedure that checks if the Email (& Mobile) entered already exists in the database. It returns True if it does (exist), False otherwise. If False is returned (i.e. email & mobile are unique), another stored procedure will insert the user details into the database and register him. All this is done on a single button click.

NEED HELP WITH THIS CODE:

EDIT 2:

```
 protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
    con.Open();



    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CheckEmailMobile", con);
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    Cmd.CommandText = "Registration";
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmailAddress.Text);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryCode", ddlCountryCode.Text);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobileNumber.Text);
    //Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Result", DbType.Boolean);
    SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@Result", DbType.Boolean);
    //sqlParam.ParameterName = "@Result";
    //sqlParam.DbType = DbType.Boolean;
    sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Write(Cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value);

}
```

Question: how do I make it work? How do I make it work with minimum resources? Am I duplicating code? I wanna do this in the most efficient/logical/correct way.

EDIT:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CheckEmailMobile]
(   @Name VARCHAR(50), 
@Email NVARCHAR(50), 
@Password NVARCHAR(50), 
@CountryCode INT, 
@Mobile VARCHAR(50), 
@Result BIT OUTPUT)
AS 
BEGIN 

  IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM AUser WHERE  [Email] = @Email AND [Mobile] = @Mobile) 
 Begin 
 Set @Result=0; --Email &/or Mobile does not exist in database
End
 ELSE
 Begin
 --Insert the record & register the user 
INSERT INTO [AUser] ([Name], [Email], [Password], [CountryCode], [Mobile]) VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Password, @CountryCode, @Mobile)  
  Set @Result=1;
 End

END
```

Comment: can you also post your `Stored Procedure` here. d most efficient way will be to write and efficient `Stored Procedure`

Comment: Please find the stored procedure in the edited post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the operation via your `usp_CheckEmailMobile` stored procedure:

Inside your stored procedure do a check like this:

```
-- Check that record doesn't exist
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 FROM AUser WHERE Email=@Email and Mobile=@Mobile)
       -- Insert record
       INSERT INTO [AUser] ([Name], [Email], [Password], [CountryCode], [Mobile]) 
       VALUES  (@Name, @Email, @Password, @CountryCode, @Mobile)
```

This will insert the record if it doesn't exist. You will just need to add the other parameters on to this stored procedure.

You can use the True / False value and say 'Registration Successful' or 'User already exists' depending on the value returned.

Comment: I also have to display the message to the user that the email/mobile is taken/avaialable...

Comment: It says you must declare (@Name, @CountryCode, @Password)

Comment: Like my post says, you need to add those params to the stored procedure

Comment: I have added the screenshot. You see the red underline. Thats where I am getting the error. It does not allow me to create a stored procedure.

Comment: Add all of the params to usp_CheckEmailMobile, they aren't currently defined

Comment: ya finally got that... need help with cs though.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected. I think you should use ExecuteScalar (since your procedure is only returning true or false). And convert to result of executescalar to boolean.

And instead of using two different procedures, you can combine them into one. The proc will first check if the email and mobile exists, if false will add the user, if true then will not add the user and return false to you.