# WCF and MVC : Call stored procedures from web mvc application

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've done a wcf service that deals with a database. In that WCF service i've created some stored procedures. That service is now accessible from my network (http: //myIP/MysService.csv/) and my stored procedures are accessible that way : http: //myIP/MysService.csv/MyProcedure?myParam=XXX.

I've a MVC4 application that is working with some local data (by local I mean a local database and a local WCF service, called that way for requests by example :

```
public int getClientID(string login)
    {
        var context = new MyLocalService.MyLocalEntityEntities(new Uri(http://localhost:12345/MyWCF.svc/));
        var persons = context.PERSON.ToList();

        var cli = from person in persons
                     where person.LOGIN == login
                     select person.CLIENT_ID;

        int cliID = (int) cli.First();
        return cliID;
    }
```

Now, I'd like to plug the 2 : delete all the part that works with local data (var context=...) and replace it by a call to the stored procedure of my WCF service. How to do it ?

I've try to add my service using right click-> add as a service reference -> http: //myIP/MysService.csv/ for address by I cannot access to stored procedures. Is it the right way to work and if not, how to do it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use Stored Procedures then look at the [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) class that will allow you to execute stored procedures on the database.

The other idea would be to consider what kind of Object-Relational Mapping tool you are using that may allow for SQL commands to be executed directly since you already seem to be using some LINQ in your code.

---

You'd pair the SqlCommand class with a SqlConnection class that have a direct connection to the database, presuming the stored procedure is MS-SQL Server or SQL Express where you want to execute the procedure in the DB.  Unless you have a very different configuration than what I've seen, most calls to stored procedures are done by wrapping some using statements for the connection and command to run the procedure.  [Calling stored procedure from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566393/calling-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp-code) has an example if you need it.

Comment: Thank you, i'm now working that way : String serviceAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WCFADDRESS"];
            DataServiceContext context = new DataServiceContext(new Uri(serviceAddress));
            List<Result> prod = context.Execute<Result>(new Uri(serviceAddress + "sp2?cid="+clientID), "GET", false).ToList(); But I have an error according to OData protocol version (that is version 1 and should be at least version 3). How to update OData protocol version ?